# How to get gzip data from the backend in angular 5 using httpclient

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I am trying get the zipped file from the backend. Please find the code for httpclient as below :

I tried multiple options in header adding content-type with different options. But not able to come up with exact template. I couldn't find anything related to get the zipped data from the server in the angular api. Please let me know if any one would have come up with something similar issue.

```
getSpecialHeaders() {
    return new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
         'specialHeader': '',
         'Content-Type': 'gzip'
    });
}

getAllUnitsReport() {
 //Function to get the gzip data
const headersSpl = this.getSpecialHeaders();
//httpoptions with different options tried in content-type and accept encoding
const httpOptions = {
  headers : headersSpl };
return this.httpClient.get(envConfig.appURL.assetAdoption, httpOptions)
  .catch((error) => {
    return Observable.of(error);
  });}
```

I get the error message after http call is successful as below :

> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Encoding` header is a response header that the server provides.

Usually the client provides a `Accept-Encoding` header to specify which content encoding you want to request.

For example: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`

See MDN on [Compressing with gzip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding#Compressing_with_gzip)

However this specific header is marked as a [forbidden header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) meaning it can't be set programmatically by Javascript that executes in a browser (still works in Node however).

Most browsers will automatically add a `Accept-Encoding` header containing all the content encodings that it supports.

Comment: Browser won't allow me to set Accept-Encoding . It is giving me erro:r Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"

Comment: This is because your browser is responsible for setting this header (I have updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks for response.. Any other alternatives for this problem in browser

Comment: What is your actual problem? Are you not getting it gzipped on the backend? Try to look at a network request and see which headers you're sending and receiving. The backend may be incorrectly configured